# what does linearly independent in C[0, 1] mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

This is a question from my textbook
[image]

I'm not quite sure what C[0, 1] mean, I tried to google the similar question and found that $C[0,1]$ usually denotes the collection of continuous functions $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, but I'm still not quite sure what $f: [0,1]$ means, does $[0,1]$ means the domain of the function, can anyone give me a straightforward example

Comment: Real continuous functions defined on $\;[0,1]\;$, that is. For example, $\;f(x)\;$ any polynomial, or $\;\cos x,\,\sin x,\,\frac1{2x^2+1}\;,\;\;\sqrt x\;$ ...

Comment: The example describes the space in words immediately after the definition: "the space of all continuous functions on $0 \lt t \le 1$." "On" means domain.

Comment: To show that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are linearly independent functions, your need to show that no linear combination of these functions is identically the zero function on your domain which is $[0,1]$. Take any linear combination $c_1\sin(t) + c_2\cos(t)$, assume that the $c_i$(atleast one of which is non-zero) exist such that it is zero for all $t$, and derive a contradiction. That gives you linear independence. Similarly, $t$ and $t^2$ are linearly independent functions on the whole of the real line, more so $[0,1]$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг but why we need to have all continuous functions on 0<t<1, can't we just directly say 0<t<1?

Answer (score 3):

$f:A\to B$ means that $f$ is a function whose domain is $A$ and such that $f(a)\in B$ for every $a\in A.$

$C[0,1]$ is the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\mathcal R.$

$C[0,1]$ is a vector space over the reals under the definition $(r f+g)(t)=r f(t)+g(t)$ for $f,g \in C[0,1]$ and $r\in \mathcal R$ and every $t\in [0,1].$

The zero-vector of the space $C[0,1]$ is the constant function that maps $[0,1]$ onto the set $\{0\}.$ So what you are asked is: If $r_1,r_2\in \mathcal R$ and if $r_1\cos t+r_2\sin t=0$ for every $t\in [0,1]$ then does  $r_1=r_2=0?$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm just thinking  why it need to have something like "the set of continuous functions from [0,1]", can't we make it simpler by explicitly stating that $t\in [0,1]$?

Comment: The problem is not about  any  particular value of $ t$ , but about the set of all $ t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I understand it should be a set of all [0,1], can't we just say $\forall t$ in $[0,1] $? And  the set of all continuous functions from [0,1] really seems strange, how can "all continuous functions" produce a set $[0,1] $?